# Ada95 Array assignment changes pointer or assigning per element?

Tags: arrays, variable-assignment, atomic, ada

In Ada95, we have two arrays of the same type. If we assign one to the other like so:

```
Array_A := Array_B;
```

What will this do exactly?

Will it iterate over Array_B and assign each element to Array_A in turn? Or will it simply change the address of Array_A to the address of Array_B?

The reason for asking is that we need to know if this assignment is an atomic operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment statement copies the data.  Ada makes a distinction between objects that hold data and objects that are only "references" to data; objects that are references have types that are `access` types (such as `My_Array_P` in Simon's example).  Assigning an access type would cause the references to point at the same object; but assigning an object that isn't an access type always makes a copy of the data.

It's not entirely accurate to say that the array assignment "iterate[s] over Array_B and assign[s] each element to Array_A in turn".  If the array element types are controlled types or have controlled subcomponents, then `Array_A := Array_B;` must finalize the elements of `Array_A` and later it must adjust them, but it happens in this order: First, every element of `Array_A` is finalized (in arbitrary order).  Then the data is copied from `Array_B` to `Array_A` (this could be done one element at a time, but in many cases, a compiler could optimize this to a block copy).  Then every element of `Array_A` is adjusted (again, in arbitrary order).  Thus the semantics of `Array_A := Array_B` are different from a loop (I'm assuming the upper and lower bounds of the arrays are the same):

```
for I in Array_A'range loop
    Array_A (I) := Array_B (I);
end loop;
```

because the `Finalize` and `Adjust` calls will be done in a different order.  Normally this shouldn't have any effect on the program, if `Finalize` and `Adjust` are written correctly (if the effect is different, there's probably something strange about the program design).  However, in a case where `Finalize` deallocates memory and `Adjust` allocates new memory (such as in a typical `Unbounded_String` implementation), making the `Finalize` and `Adjust` calls in a different order could have an effect on memory fragmentation.

Answer (score 2):

The contents of Array_A end up being copies of the elements of Array_B, i.e. assignment iterates over the array, assigning each element. Ada has true array objects, unlike C.

So unless you protect the operation in something like a [protected object](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-9-4.html), the assignment is not atomic. (Wrapping array assignment in a protected object doesn't make it atomic, it just appears that way from the perspective of the rest of the application.)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming

```
type My_Array is array (1 .. 42) of Integer;
Array_A : My_Array;
Array_B : My_Array;
```

then `Array_A` and `Array_B` are distinct areas of memory, and after the assignment the bytes of `Array_A` contain a copy of the bytes of `Array_B`. Whether the transfer is done by iterating over the elements or by some equivalent of `memcpy(3)` is up to the compiler writer (`pragma Atomic_Components` affects this).

If on the other hand you have

```
type My_Array is array (1 .. 42) of Integer;
type My_Array_P is access My_Array;
Array_A : My_Array_P;
Array_B : My_Array_P;
```

then the assignment will copy the pointer, and may be atomic (you could add `pragma Atomic (My_Array_P);` or `pragma Atomic (Array_A);` to tell the compiler to make the access values atomic, or fail to compile the code if it can't).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your **problem** is that you should declare the objects "Atomic", if you want the compiler to make assignments to them atomic.

If your target CPU doesn't have a suitable atomic instruction for the type of the objects, it will complain.  In that case you have (at least) one alternative solution:

1. Encapsulate the arrays in protected objects to ensure that operations on them are atomic.

Using access types and copying references is of course an option, but it is effectively a completely different operation, so you should think carefully about if that is really what you want.

(If the arrays in question are short, packed arrays of booleans, your compiler is likely to be able to make the objects "Atomic", otherwise I wouldn't expect it.)